# When including resources DRF returns my soft deleted records

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, json-api

I have DRF API that supports including the books of an author in an `authors` get request.

Our API has a soft delete system where Book(2) marked as deleted.

But when I do the request below Book(2) is still included in the response.

I would like to have only Book(1) in the response of this request.

`GET` http://localhost/authors/2?include=books

API returns to me:

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "Author",
        "id": "2",
        "attributes": {...},
        "relationships": {
            "books": {
                "meta": {
                    "count": 2
                },
                "data": [
                    {
                        "type": "Book",
                        "id": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Book",
                        "id": "2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "included": [
        {
            "type": "Book",
            "id": "1",
            "attributes": {...}
        },
        {
            "type": "Book",
            "id": "2",
            "attributes": {...}
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a `BaseModel` that handles the soft deletion overriding the `delete` method:

```
class BaseModel(Model):
    archive = BoolYesNoField(db_column="archive", default=False, null=False)
    created = DateTimeField(db_column="created", auto_now_add=True, null=False)
    updated = DateTimeField(db_column="updated", auto_now=True, null=False)

    objects = BaseManager()
    all_objects = BaseManager(alive_only=False)

    def delete(self):
        self.archive = True
        self.save()
        relate_obj_delete(self)

    def hard_delete(self):
        super(Model, self).delete()

    def undelete(self):
        self.archive = False
        self.save()
```

**Manager**

```
class BaseManager(Manager):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.alive_only = kwargs.pop("alive_only", True)
        super(BaseManager, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.alive_only:
            return BaseQuerySet(self.model).filter(archive=False)
        return BaseQuerySet(self.model)

    def hard_delete(self):
        return self.get_queryset().hard_delete()
```

**AuthorViewSet**

```
class AuthorViewSet(BaseViewSet):
    queryset = Author.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AuthorSerializer
    filterset_class = AuthorFilterSet
```

**Serializer**

```
class AuthorSerializer(BaseSerializer):
    books = ResourceRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
    included_serializers = {
        "books": BookSerializer,
    }

    class Meta(BaseSerializer.Meta):
        model = Author
```

If someone could just point me out in the right direction I would be really helpful.
There is probably a function that I need to override somewhere but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It will be difficult to answer your questions as this. Please provide context, snippet and details like in a [mcve]. A good start would be the piece of code that handle deletion and an example on how you call it.

Comment: How is soft delete implemented, do you have some custom default manager on the model? Please add the models, serializers and view

Comment: @IainShelvington I added code snippets for all involved classes. Let me know if anything else is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in your serializer. By default Django will use [`Model._base_manager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/managers/#django.db.models.Model._base_manager) to fetch related objects and not your custom manager. You need to specify in your nested [ResourceRelatedField](https://django-rest-framework-json-api.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#resourcerelatedfield) field which manager you would like to use

```
class AuthorSerializer(BaseSerializer):
    books = ResourceRelatedField(
        queryset=Book.objects,
        many=True,
        read_only=True
    )
    ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately I will have to remove `read_only=True` otherwise I get this error: `AssertionError: Relational fields should not provide a queryset argument, when setting read_only=True`